# Delete and insert new buttons when a button is clicked in a table in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on a swift project, i have a table view with 3 cells, i want to delete all buttons in a third cell and insert new buttons when a someone clicks any button on the second cell, the code goes like this

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell: DateTableViewCell!
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            // First row code goes here
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            for index in 0...6 {
                var button: UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as!UIButton
                button.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(intXTile), CGFloat(28), CGFloat(40), CGFloat(30))
                button.setTitle("Button Title", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
                cell.addSubview(button)
            }
        } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
            // Third row code goes here 
        }
    }

    func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton!) {
        var btn:UIButton = sender
        let subviews = sender.superview?.superview?.subviews as! [UIView]
        for aSubview in self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 0))!.contentView.subviews {
            if aSubview is UIButton {
                aSubview.removeFromSuperview()
            }

            var answerText: Array<String?> = ["Button5","Button6","Button7","Button8"]

            var answerButton: Array<UIButton> = []

            for var i = 0; i<=answerText.count; i++ {

                var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as! UIButton

                button.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)

                button.titleLabel!.lineBreakMode = .ByTruncatingTail

                var numberOfButton = 5
                let j = i
                var y:CGFloat  = (CGFloat)(j*290/(numberOfButton+1)-1);
                button.frame.size.height = 30
                button.frame.size.width = 200
                button.frame.origin.y = y
                button.frame.origin.x = 50.0
                answerButton .insert(button, atIndex: i)

            }

            for var i = 0; i<answerText.count; i++ {

                var button:UIButton = answerButton [i]

                button.setTitle(answerText[i], forState: UIControlState.Normal)

                aSubview.addSubview(button)
            }

    }
     }
```

The Data Table View Controller Scene in Story Board Goes like this

[image]

when any of the second cell buttons are clicked the "buttonClicked" method will be called, there i need to delete and update the buttons with new data, right now its adding new buttons to the third cell but its not deleting the existing buttons, also i need to place the buttons properly within the third cell, I'm struggling get this done from last 2 days, can someone please help me on this, thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: I'm using Dynamic Prototypes, with 3 Prototype Cells

Comment: You should reload tableview or concrete cell while changing cell content data. To get cell you should call it by indexpath or tag

Comment: Thanks, can you please guide me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code

```
let contents = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 0))?.contentView
for i in 1...3 {
    contents.viewWithTag(i)?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: I have tried the above code inside "buttonClicked" method, but it says "could not find member forEach", can please explain there are so many for loops, where exactly i need to add it, thanks a lot

Comment: @sam are you using Swift 2?

Comment: Sorry it does not work, can please tell me after which for loop i need to add?

Comment: @sam add it after `for v in subviews`. Are you using that line to insert the cells though?

Comment: @sam wait I just realised that something else needs to change, I'll update my answer again.

Comment: yes, thanks a lot for helping me :) i think I'm almost there, just need some more tweaks

Comment: In the `buttonClicked` method, you should remove all your code, just keep the `for` loop of @kabiroberai and your `for index in 0...6 ` loop. Others are redundant.

Comment: @t4nhpt  yes i have tried that, it works when i dont insert new buttons, then it removes all buttons but when i add new buttons it does not clear the previous buttons

Comment: Do you need to delete buttons of all cell or only the third cell? Your previous code should delete buttons of first and second cell, too. The @kabiroberai 's code delete only button in third cell

Comment: I want to delete only third cell buttons

Comment: @kabiroberai still no luck with .contentView :(

Comment: @kabiroberai i have updated my "buttonclicked" function with your answer, but it does not clear the previous buttons, can you please help me thanks a lot

Comment: @sam can you `println()` `aSubview`?

Comment: @kabiroberai yes, it says <UIView: 0x7ffd1aa292b0; frame = (5 10; 310 382); alpha = 0.8; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ffd1aa293c0>>

Comment: @sam what about `aSubview.subviews`?

Comment: @kabiroberai it gives me [<UIView: 0x7ffd138ef790; frame = (5 10; 310 382); alpha = 0.8; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ffd138ef8a0>>]
[<UIButtonLabel: 0x7ffd1c3af7f0; frame = (78 8; 44.5 14.5); text = 'Button1'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7ffd138fbc80>>]
[<UIButtonLabel: 0x7ffd1c3b7220; frame = (78 8; 44.5 14.5); text = 'Button2'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7ffd1c3b73e0>>] till Button4

Comment: actually the table row is not updating, can we implement something like aSubview.reloadData?

Comment: @kabiroberai if you check my Data Table View Controller Scene in the Story Board i have deleted the View under timeCell, can you please ensure that it is correct? still no luck :(

Comment: @kabiroberai Thanks again, but it shows runtime exception error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" in this line for aSubview in self.tableView.cell...

Comment: Oh, the subview with the buttons must be at a particular index then. Let me update the answer again :p

Comment: @sam should I move this to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93069/discussion-between-sam-and-kabiroberai).